# Stream a generated tone

Tags: c#, audio, asp.net-mvc-4, audio-streaming, html5-audio

I want to generate tones with System.Beep and stream the tone to the user from a web application. I'm thinking my options are:

- Stream the tone as it's generated somehow.
- Save a wav file and use the `<audio>` tag to play the audio.

I would like to try streaming the tone as it's generated but I can't figure out how that would be done or if that's even possible.

Comment: basically it is possible but I would be surprised if `System.Beep` would be part of that implementation... you need to generate the sound "in chunks" as a response to the `HTTP GET` which is issued by the html5 audio tat from the clients browser...

Comment: `System.Beep` isn't possible.  You need to create a proper audio stream, in a codec supported by the client.

Comment: I've been playing with it some and I think it's possible to do what I want to do with a bit of hacking but I don't think it will be practical for my situation. I'll probably do this as a WPF application instead.

Comment: You can also generate tones on the client side using Web Audio API http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/ (no Microsft support though)

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at [IIS media services](http://www.iis.net/media); they are capable of serving the streaming audio. A simple solution would be to essentially originate a podcast using something like expression encoder. With the podcast happening to be your beeps.